# How to embed facebook in SvelteKit?

Tags: facebook, svelte, embed, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit project, where I wish to embed a Facebook page. If I put the Javascript SDK from the Facebook page plugin in my `+page.svelte`, then the embed deafults to its fallback link:

```
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/page" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/page">page</a></blockquote>
```

The facebook page plugin site tells to put the SDK after the opening `body` tag. So I went to `app.html` and put it after the body tag:

```
<body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover">
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v17.0" nonce="e9RAV0kx"></script>
    <div style="display: contents">
        %sveltekit.body%
    </div>
</body>
```

Still doesn't work. So I decided to also put the embed `div` in the body tag just to see if it would render at all:

```
<body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover">
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v17.0" nonce="e9RAV0kx"></script>
    <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/page" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="" data-height="" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="false"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/page" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/page">page</a></blockquote></div>
    <div style="display: contents">
        %sveltekit.body%
    </div>
</body>
```

It did, but obviusly I want to render it in `+page.svelte` not `app.html`. Is there any way of embedding Facebook in SvelteKit?